# Нужны ли запятые?

Tags: запятая

И уже как раньше невозможно спорить...

Answer (score 4):

Смотря какой смысл.Если "невозможно спорить" как?-как раньше,по-прежнему, так же -обстоятельство,тесно примыкающее по смыслу к глаголу,запятых нет, это не сравнительный оборот.

Если смысл в том, что нет смысла, невозможно спорить, как это уже было и раньше,то запятые нужны с двух сторон -как обособление пояснения. Я бы выбрала первый вариант, без запятых.

Comment: Благодарю, Людмила!